# Which training courses in geostatistics can you recommend?

Tags: interpolation, spatial-statistics, education

I'm looking for excellent geostatistics courses all over the world, including online courses. In particular, I would like to learn more about the kriging method. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://geostat-course.org/node - they have lots of courses, great resources.

I would recommend taking a look at a couple of very good books:

- [Elementary Statistics for Geographers, Third Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1572304847)
- [Practical Statistics for Geographers and Earth Scientists](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470849142.html)
- [An Introduction to Applied Geostatistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195050134) [Geostatistics: Modeling Spatial
  Uncertainty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470183152)

Esri also has excellent documentation on kriging and geostats, look [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Understanding_interpolation_analysis/009z0000006w000000/).

Answer (score -1):

Coursera has a lot of great courses. I know that they had a geostatistics course in the past. Maybe something will appear soon.
https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=statistics